# Java - Tree Structure to JSON object

Tags: java, json, tree, jackson

I have a tree structure modeled on the following template: https://github.com/gt4dev/yet-another-tree-structure/blob/master/java/src/com/tree/TreeNode.java

I'd like to dump the entire tree into a JSON object. I have looked into using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) but I have a hard time finding adequate usage examples for this particular task.

EDIT: I should have been clearer that what I'm looking for is a JSON file that has the same structure as the original tree, as such what I'm looking for is something like:

```
{
    "root": data {
        "child 1": "data child 1",
        "child 2": "data child 2" { 
              "child of child 2": "data..."
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a string format - a linear one.

A tree is not a linear data type.

With these, you need to decide on how a tree looks like as a string.

You can try:

- Make a tuple string: `"A(B(E,F),C(G,H))"`
- Traversing a tree and making an array out of it: `["A", "B", C"]`
- Creating a table/map of parent-children pairings: `[{"node":"A","children":["B","C"]},{"node":"B","children":["E","F"]}]`
- ...or maybe something else, *be creative!*